# Overlap jQuery search box

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to overlap a search box on a menu. I have followed this tutorial for adding the search box: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ExpandingSearchBar/

However, it doesn't overlap. But I want it to overlap.

What's the correct way of overlapping the div over a text/li/div?

P.S: I want it to be `float:right`

IS this possible?

Comment: Where is your CSS? What have you tried ?? Where is your code for menu ?

Comment: I have tried this: `width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;`

Comment: Add it to your question, better styled. Show us what you have of code - we don't follow links and tutorials nilly willy here to dismantle them. Show us your code and you'll find help :)